# Django: Use same request date on page refresh

Tags: django, django-forms, django-request

I'm building a django app. I have a function in my view that proceeds a POST form request and the renders an page dependent on it:
It looks simple like that:

```
def renderPage(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExampleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Do something with the form data

            #here i render the page and pass some data to it
            return render(request, "main/mypage.html", {"example" : example, ...})
    ...
```

This works just like it should. But now i want if someone is on the rendered Page an he reloads the page (for example in chrome by clicking on the address-bar an pressing enter) that the previews request he made is preserved. 
I the moment when somebody is reloading the page the renderPage() function is called but there is no request (obviously then of course the request.method == 'POST' statement is False). Is there any easy way to achieve this? Is this a problem/feature of the browser? Is it something i have to do in my html code?

I can only thing of very complicated ways to do this. Like for example explicitly saving the request data and then writing a script in JavaScript that creates a copy of the previous request when someone reloades the page. I'm pretty sure there is a simpler way in django to achieve this!?

Comment: You could save the data in the session, then check there on page load if the request is not a POST.

Comment: @DanielRoseman This works perfect an is very simple. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">       
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-store, must-revalidate">       
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="expires" CONTENT="0">
```

or reload data using js

Comment: Sry doesn't work for me ... I solved is by using the session data like proposed by @Daniel Roseman